# Script select vb.net 2012

Tags: html, vb.net

How do I select the "Mr" option ? I tried and it did not work!

```
<div id="select-title" class="wrapper-dropdown-3 active" tabindex="1">
  <span>Mr</span>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li>
      <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Mr</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Ms</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Mrs</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Miss</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Dr</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Other</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Title is required" id="title" name="Title" type="hidden" value="Mr">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Unordered lists (UL) are not server controls.  They can be selected via JS/JQuery, but not asp.net.  Could you explain what you mean by "selected".  This could be a JS command, or some style sheet, or something else.

Comment: Hi, your tag [vb.net] doesn't match the nature of the question, you'd be better removing the [vb.net] tag and adding a [html] tag

Comment: corrected indents in code, added new tag